# A-Frame: how to animate objects on scene with scenario

Tags: animation, three.js, aframe

Let's speak about 3D movies or smth like that. Ok, I know how to animate properties with `<a-animation>`. I also tried [`aframe-animation-component`](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe) based on animejs. I love animejs. It have useful `anime.timeline()`. You can just set frames of this and animate much objects as you want. But it have very serious trouble: it isn't able animate complex attributes like `position` or `scale` or another serialized component. This trouble I've described [here](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/211). Animejs's timeline is perfect for DOM, but very hard to use with A-Frame.
I also found [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes_json) for three.js. May be I can generate same animation for my A-Frame scene? Looking for any suggestions about scene's keyframes or timelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-timeline-component

I published the animation timeline component.

```
<a-scene animation-timeline__1="timeline: #myTimeline; loop: true">
```

```
<a-timeline id="myTimeline">
  <a-timeline-animation select="#text1" name="togglevisible"></a-timeline-animation>
  <a-timeline-animation select="#text1" name="fadein"></a-timeline-animation>
  <a-timeline-animation select="#text1" name="fadeout"></a-timeline-animation>
  <a-timeline-animation select="#text1" name="togglevisibleoff"></a-timeline-animation>

  <a-timeline-group>
    <a-timeline-animation select="a-entity[mixin~=box]" name="fadein"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="a-entity[mixin~=box]" name="scale"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="a-entity[mixin~=box]" name="color"></a-timeline-animation>
  </a-timeline-group>

  <a-timeline-group>
    <a-timeline-animation select="#text2" name="togglevisible"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="#text2" name="fadein"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="#text2" name="textcolor"></a-timeline-animation>
  </a-timeline-group>

  <a-timeline-animation select="#text2" name="fadeout"></a-timeline-animation>
  <a-timeline-animation select="#text2" name="togglevisibleoff"></a-timeline-animation>

  <a-timeline-animation select="#text3" name="togglevisible"></a-timeline-animation>
  <a-timeline-group>
    <a-timeline-animation select="a-entity[mixin~=box]" name="color"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="a-entity[mixin~=box]" name="rotate"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="a-entity[mixin~=box]" name="position"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="#text3" name="fadein"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="#text3" name="positionin"></a-timeline-animation>
  </a-timeline-group>

  <a-timeline-animation select="#text3" name="positionout"></a-timeline-animation>
  <a-timeline-animation select="#text3" name="togglevisibleoff"></a-timeline-animation>

  <a-timeline-animation select="#text4" name="togglevisible"></a-timeline-animation>

  <a-timeline-group>
    <a-timeline-animation select="#sky" name="color"></a-timeline-animation>
    <a-timeline-animation select="#text4" name="fadein"></a-timeline-animation>
  </a-timeline-group>

  <a-timeline-animation select="#text4" name="fadeout" offset="500"></a-timeline-animation>
</a-timeline>

<a-mixin id="box"
  geometry="primitive: box"
  material="color: #AAA; opacity: 0"
  animation__fadein="property: material.opacity; dur: 2000; from: 0; to: 1; autoplay: false"
  animation__scale="property: scale; to: 2 20 2; dur: 2000; easing: easeInOutElastic; autoplay: false"
  animation__position="property: position; to: 0 30 -3; dur: 2000; autoplay: false"
  animation__color="property: material.color; from: #AAA; to: #222; dur: 2500; autoplay: false"
  animation__rotate="property: rotation; to: 0 360; dur: 1000; easing: easeInQuad; autoplay: false"
  scale="0.0001 0.0001 0.0001"
></a-mixin>

<a-mixin id="text"
  text="align: center; color: #333; width: 6; opacity: 0"
  animation__fadein="property: text.opacity; from: 0; to: 1; dur: 3000; easing: linear; autoplay: false"
  animation__fadeout="property: text.opacity; from: 1; to: 0; dur: 3000; easing: linear; autoplay: false"
  animation__togglevisible="property: visible; from: false; to: true; dur: 1; autoplay: false"
  animation__togglevisibleoff="property: visible; from: true; to: false; dur: 1; autoplay: false"
  position="0 2 -3"
  visible="false"></a-mixin>
```

Comment: Huh, thank you, but I've created my own timeline library https://github.com/Disorrder/animated-js

Comment: animejs has timelines built in. The animation component integrates it for A-Frame in a smart way.

Comment: Yes, but I don't like this style. Anyway you implemented this feature after half year after question, I have already solved. And I think, I made much better than `anime.timeline`
At least, I can use it in pure Three.js app, in Playcanvas, and so on

Comment: Thank you Disorder, I feel the animation-timeline-components "simple" examples are anything but simple for me. Yours I can follow.